# Problem identifying moss features from GUIDS

Tags: sharepoint, dependencies

We are using a site definition and it has 3 feature dependencies that we are struggling to identify:

```
<ActivationDependency FeatureId="7EDD3C9C-8AC6-4ab5-A209-30B5DC422464" />
<ActivationDependency FeatureId="63FDC6AC-DBB4-4247-B46E-A091AEFC866F" />
<ActivationDependency FeatureId="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416" />
```

Can anyone identify what these features or give me an idea as to how to identify them?

I think they are out of the box moss features but they are not installed on the farm currently.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Is the site definition out of the box as well or from a common source (e.g. codeplex)?  Might make it easier to track down.

Answer (score 2):

[22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416](http://www.katriendg.com/aboutdotnet/2007-5-1-publishing-web-syntax-onet-xml.aspx) - Publishing Web Feature

The other two GUIDs are not googleable and don't return any results on MSDN. Are they Microsoft features, or could they be 3rd party?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Copernic Dekstop search is a tool called Agent Ransack from Mythicsoft. It allows for really good text search in files (in the FEATURES folder of the 12 hive in your case) and it is free. Download it [here](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Copernic Desktop Search](http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/index.html) and have indexed a copy of the 12 hive. I frequently use it to search for out of the box and custom features by GUID, just as you are.

As Andrew said, 7EDD3C9C-8AC6-4ab5-A209-30B5DC422464 and 
63FDC6AC-DBB4-4247-B46E-A091AEFC866F are not standard features as they were not in the 12 hive. But if you download Copernic (or use a similar search tool) and point it at your solution, you should be able to find the feature definitions pretty quickly.